# error An unexpected error occurred: "Commit hash required"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

when I using this command to add eslint(`@vue/cli 4.5.15`):

```
vue add eslint
```

shows error like this:

```
 WARN  There are uncommitted changes in the current repository, it's recommended to commit or stash them first.
? Still proceed? Yes

  Installing @vue/cli-plugin-eslint...

yarn add v1.22.17
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/crx-selection-translate/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
error An unexpected error occurred: "Commit hash required".
 ERROR  command failed: yarn add @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@~4.5.0 -D
```

what should I do to fix this problem? I already have tried to remove the lock file but still did not fix this problem. the node version is `v16.13.2`.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: NO, I did not found a solution yet.@RohitMittal

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This usually happens when a you use `npm install` on a yarn project, then `yarn install` when you realize npm didn't work. Somehow `yarn.lock` gets corrupted. Here is what I do:

```
rm package-lock.json
rm yarn.lock
git checkout <old-hash> yarn.lock
```

Answer (score 5):

For me I did the following and it works:

```
$ rm package-lock.json    # remove the package-lock.json file

$ yarn install  # install successfully and update the yarn.lock file
```